# Returning a string array from JsonResult and using it in a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to query a database, and get the result in my webpage, however it has to be done through JavaScript (Ajax, jQuery). I have googled for hours, and nothing ever works. It either throws a parser error, saying `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`, or just comes out as undefined.

I am using the following JsonResult method:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult NextArticle(int slideID)
{
    var articles = db.Slides.ToList();
    var currentArticle = db.Slides.First(s => s.SlideId == slideID);
    int articlePosition = articles.IndexOf(currentArticle);
    articlePosition = (articlePosition + 1) >= articles.Count() ? 0 : articlePosition + 1;

    var nextArticle = articles.ElementAt(articlePosition);

    //nextArticle.Article.ArticleText.Substring(0, 50)+"..."
    string[] returnParameters = { 
                                    nextArticle.SlideId.ToString(),
                                    nextArticle.Image.ImageURL,
                                    nextArticle.Article.ArticleTitle,
                                    nextArticle.Article.ArticleText
                                };
    return Json(returnParameters);
}
```

And the following JavaScript function:

```
function nextSlide() {
    var articleLink = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../SlideShow/NextArticle",
        data: {
            slideID: articleLink.getAttribute("id"),
        },
        dataType: 'json', //Some places are saying I should leave this out
        success: function (result) {
            $(articleLink).id = result[0];
            document.getElementById("articleImage").setAttribute("src", result[1]);
            document.getElementById("articleTitle").innerHTML = result[2];
            document.getElementById("articleText").innerHTML = result[3];
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: does your controller get the data correctly.

Comment: try putting contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Comment: @AmmarCSE I added `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` under the `dataType: 'json',` and it is still throwing the parser error. I also tried leaving the `dataType: 'json',` out, but it doesn't affect it

Comment: what exactly is the parser error?

Comment: @AmmarCSE there's an unexpected end of input

Comment: Sorry, I have to go now. But paste the exact wording of the error please. Ill take a look when I get back

Comment: @AmmarCSE the error is: `Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: @user3189142, try putting traditional:true in your ajax options

Comment: @user3189142, try putting traditional:true and let me know if it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

No need to use "**`dataType: 'json'`**"

as you are already sending Json Data. so its already parsed.

Json data is sent in Key-Value pair. and you are not accessing this way.

you are not using **"result"** argument any where in code.

**result** is array. and access key/index this way in my case "status_code" is objec/variable I want to access it value..

result.status_code == 200;

```
success: function (result) {
            result.status_code == 200;
            $(articleLink).id = result.arrayKey_1;
            document.getElementById("articleImage").setAttribute("src", result.arrayKey_1);
            document.getElementById("articleTitle").innerHTML = result.arrayKey_2;
            document.getElementById("articleText").innerHTML = result.arrayKey_3;
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I change a bit some of your code , so this might be work.
your solution is the hard way, this is the simple and easy way.
instead of using array of string as returned object use the object!

First create a view model class for returning an object of article as Json result in the action method:

```
    public class ArticleViewModel
    {
        public int SlideID { get; set; }
        public String ImageURL { get; set; }
        public String ArticleTitle { get; set; }
        public String ArticleText { get; set; }
    }
```

Then your JsonResult method will be :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult NextArticle(int slideID)
    {
        var articles = db.Slides.ToList();
        var currentArticle = db.Slides.First(s => s.SlideId == slideID);
        int articlePosition = articles.IndexOf(currentArticle);
        int nextArticlePosition = articlePosition > articles.Count() ? 0 : articlePosition + 1;

        var nextArticle = articles.ElementAt(nextArticlePosition);

        //nextArticle.Article.ArticleText.Substring(0, 50)+"..."

        var result = new ArticleViewModel()
        {
            SlideID = nextArticle.SlideId,
            ImageURL = nextArticle.Image.ImageURL,
            ArticleTitle = nextArticle.Article.ArticleTitle,
            ArticleText = nextArticle.Article.ArticleText,

        };
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And the Javascript function to handle the response is :

```
    function nextSlide() {
    var articleLink = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

    $.getJSON('../SlideShow/NextArticle',
                { slideID: articleLink.getAttribute("id") },
                function (receivedData) {
                    $(articleLink).id = receivedData.SlideID;
                    $('#articleImage').attr('src', receivedData.ImageURL);
                    $('#articleTitle').html(receivedData.ArticleTitle);
                    $('#articleText').html(receivedData.ArticleText);
                })
    .fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    })
    ;

}
```

You can access the return Json object values via key's names simply. i change the code that uses more JQuery functions. and i use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead of $.post so the received data is in Json format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to

- explicitly set `Content Type` in [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- pass JSON string using [JSON.stringify Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc836459%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Example:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../SlideShow/NextArticle",
        data: JSON.stringify({'slideID': articleLink.getAttribute("id")}), 
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {
           //process result here..
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           //process error here..
        }
    });
```